# Check if number is greater than 18 using Java @Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to check using @Pattern if the passed number is over 18. Currently, I have this:

```
@Pattern (regexp="18|19|[2-9][0-9]|\\d{3,}")
```

but I still get

```
No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'age'
```

What should I change to make this validaton?

Comment: Might I ask why you want to validate this with a regular expression pattern? This seems like deliberately choosing a needlessly complicated and unfitting validation method. If I wanted to validate if a number is greater than 18, I would just use a simple number comparison method like a simple greater than check.

Comment: And FWIW, 001 will be judged as 'over 18' by that regular expression.

Comment: [Stop Hammering Nails with a Screwdriver](https://medium.com/hashicorp-engineering/stop-hammering-nails-with-a-screwdriver-9a2c6c5706ac). RegEx is not the right tool for this requirement.

Comment: `'java.lang.Integer'` obviously you can’t validate an Integer using RegEx. Use javax.validation.constraints.Min instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is having numeric datatype whereas the pattern and regex works on String datatype. Change from `int` to `String` or `TypeCast` it to get the desired output.

Also use `18|19|\\d{3,}|[2-9][0-9]` as when it will check for numbers with 3 digit or more for your regex `18|19|[2-9][0-9]|\\d{3,}` it will get first 2 digit even if its more than 2 digits.

```
18         \\ Will check if 18
|          \\ Or
19         \\ Will check if 19
|          \\ Or
\\d{3,}    \\ Will check for numbers of 3 digit or more
|          \\ Or
[2-9][0-9] \\ Will check for numbers between 20 and 99
```

`This means that if it is not 18 it will check for 19 and if not it will check for numbers of 3 digit or more and if not then it will check for number between 20 and 99`

---

Comment: `000` is three digits and would match as "over 18" — Regex is absolutely the wrong tool to use.  Convert to an integer and compare, or as Christoph said in a comment use `javax.validation.constraints.Min`